# Selecting a css id adjacent to a class

Tags: css

I would like to select an id only when it follows a specific class.

Would something like `.class + #id { css }` work?  or is there another way to do this?

I'm trying to select `#jp-relatedposts` only if they follow `.single_job_listing`

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `.single_job_listing ~ #jp-relatedposts {...}` work?

Comment: Have you tried `.class + #id { css }`? Did it work? Also: Never post screenshots of your code, that's no fun to work with. Please post your code as text.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first ever post on stack overflow.  Next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

The selector `+` will work. It will only select the div with the ID indicated `#jp-relatedposts` if it is just after the element with the class `.single_job_listing`.

As an example:

### HTML

```
<div id="main" class="site-main">
  <div class="single_job_listing">
    Your job listing
  </div>
  <div id="jp-relatedposts" class="jp-relatedposts">
    Related Posts
  </div>
  <div id="jp-non-relatedposts" class="jp-relatedposts">
    Non-related Posts
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.single_job_listing + #jp-relatedposts, .single_job_listing + #jp-non-relatedposts {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.jp-relatedposts {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

[Running example](https://jsfiddle.net/dharillo/f9vhmuyk/)

Only the `#jp-relatedposts` will be selected by the *cyan* rule, while the `#jp-non-relatedposts` will have the default background color.

You can read more about the siblings selectors from [here](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/#article-header-id-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>` for example

**HTML**

```
<div class="job-listing">
<a class="job">Job</a>
</div>
```

--

**CSS**

```
.job-listing > .job {
    color: white;//your colorname or colorcode
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work in this particular case as the `>` selector selects element  `b` where the parent of element `b` is  element `a` in this example `a > b {...}` The OP is looking for a sibling selector where both elements `a` and `b` are on the same level

Comment: mmm.. not quite sure i understand.

Comment: `a > b` only selects `b` elements that are inside `a` elements.  If `b` is outside of `a` then using `a > b` would not successfully select it. If you want to select `b` when it's next to `a` (on the same level) you use `a ~ b {...}`

Comment: Thank you so much a ~ b worked!!!  Could you explain how a + b would have been different?

Comment: @KSaft No problem. Glad it worked for you. The `+` selector selects all `b` elements the are **immediately** placed after `a` elements in this example `a + b {...}` . It would work if you only have one `b` element and it's placed **immediately** after an `a` element. If there are any other elements in between `a` and `b`, it wouldn't work. Further, If there are multiple `b` elements, it would only select the one **immediately** after `a` elements but none of the other `b` elements would be selected